# Alternative to requery on Android honeycomb

Tags: android, database, cursor, android-3.0-honeycomb

As google in there "wisdom" has ditched requery on cursor I am looking for alternatives.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

It helpfully says "Just request a new cursor, so you can do this asynchronously and update your list view once the new cursor comes back."

However does this mean I now need to keep a record of the search run on each cursor so I can run it again ??

Wondering what people are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CursorLoader` works great with `ListView` and `CursorAdapter`. The problem is that you'll have to write your own `ContentProvider`. This is not that much of work and is *very* worth it.

If you are using the Cursor without putting it in an `Adapter` you can probably use `AsyncQueryHandler` instead and manually observing changes via `Cursor.registerContentObserver()`. Note that this approach also requires a `ContentProvider`.

If you really don't want to implement a `ContentProvider` you'll have to implement your own async query method or stick to `requery()`, don't do this though.

Comment: THanks, what annoys me is this quote from Android site on maxsdkversion  Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended. First, there is no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible

Comment: Yeah, you can safely continue using the old approach if you really want to. I has been deprecated as it performs the query on the UI thread (which means disk IO) and this is a big no-no.

Comment: I think the problem is actually before if you ran requery on a closed cursor it would ignore you - now it flips out. Which is not a bad thing !. I think for now I will patch it up and then redo the code in this area in a later revision.

Comment: It does that now? If that's the case it's a bug which may (will?) cause older applications to crash. Please report it at the bug tracker then!

Comment: Well verified on a Motorola XOOM and the emulator.  on 2.3 or below the following worked :      if(mCursor!=null)
     {
       mCursor.requery();
     }
     now I have to do :      if(mCursor!=null)
     {
      if(mCursor.isClosed()==false)
      {
       mCursor.requery();
      }
     }
     Not the biggest change in the world, but it is incompatible - point me at the bug tracker and I will raise

Comment: Here is the issue for reference: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16098